# R ggplot iterate through list of pollutants for graph titles

Tags: r, list, loops, expression, ggtitle

I want to produce multiple graphs from a single dataframe listing different pollutant levels in different cities.  I can loop through data slices without difficulty to plot pollutant levels, but I cannot create a different title for each graph in a loop.  The graph titles include chemical formulae.

```
qdf = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
PolTitle <- expression(paste(NO[2], " pollutant values"))
MultiTitles = list(expression(paste(NO[2], " pollutant values")), 
   expression(paste(PM[2.5], " pollutant values")))
ggplot(qdf, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(PolTitle)        # displays correctly
ggplot(qdf, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(MultiTitles[2])  # unexpected parsing
```

[correct graph title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3zfs.png)

[incorrect graph title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY2ZY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[` instead of `[` or use `c` instead of `list`:

```
qdf = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
PolTitle <- expression(paste(NO[2], " pollutant values"))
MultiTitles = list(expression(paste(NO[2], " pollutant values")), 
                   expression(paste(PM[2.5], " pollutant values")))
ggplot(qdf, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(PolTitle)
ggplot(qdf, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(MultiTitles[[2]])
```